# Can't log in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS when upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, upgrade

I use Dual OS - Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Windows 8.1.
When I uprade ubuntu 16.04 LTS and start it, I can not enter log in user.
[[Image] Can't enter login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2j5OB.jpg).
And I hit ENTER, it appear a black screen with line. After it back on log in window.

```
/dev/sda2: clean, xxx/xxx files, xxx/xxx blocks
```

[[Image] black screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbPGV.png)

I search google with similar prolem, but failed.
Help me fix this error, please!!!

Comment: Press up arrow and then type your password and hit Enter.